# SQL multi table query working slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

```
bag_of_words(
    ch_id,
    frequency,
    number,w_id
)

clinical_history(
    ch_complete,
    ch_id,p_id
)

patients(
    p_id,
    p_name
)

words(
    w_id,
    w_word
)
```

and I have a list of selected words. I need to select from tables `w_word`, `p_name`, `number`, `freqency`, and `ch_id`.

I have this query, but it is slow and I need it to be faster

```
SELECT  
    w_word, 
    p_name, 
    number, 
    frequency, 
    bag_of_words.ch_id
FROM
    bag_of_words
LEFT JOIN 
    words 
ON 
    words.w_id=bag_of_words.w_id
LEFT JOIN 
    clinical_history 
ON 
    bag_of_words.ch_id=clinical_history.ch_id
LEFT JOIN 
    patients 
ON 
    patients.p_id=clinical_history.p_id
WHERE 
    words.w_word IN (',,,,,')
```

Comment: i think without join, it will working fast but i couldnot find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use views for increase query performance. (Check: [Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)). By the way, are you using indexes ? Indexes also increase performance.

Comment: indexes will increase your performance. And Also check views. Creating Views will increase performance

Comment: is there a way for making query without join

Comment: You can use subqueries instead of join. But i suggest you to use join. Did you check creating views ?

Comment: is view or create temp table better?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an index on w_word, and making sure all the columns that you join on have indexes.

If you're still getting really slow queries, try eliminating joins to figure out which part of the query is causing the slow-down.  Then concentrate on optimising that.

There are loads of tools out there that can be used to analyse individual queries, and see what needs to be done to speed them up.

Comment: can you recommend any tool?

Comment: @user2605046 I've not used it, but I think http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html is supposed to help with it